# Filter DataTable based on a Dictionary

Tags: linq, dictionary, datatable

I have a DataTable I would like to filter based on elements in a Dictionary. 
The Dictionary key is an integer and the value portion is a class.

The contained class has a field called ItemId. This ItemId is a field in the datatable.

I have a value for the key portion of the dictionary.

What I would like is a LINQ query which returns an Enumerable subset of the datatable based on the value I have for the key.

In other words I want a result set of all records in the datatable whose ItemId column is in records contained in the dictionary for which I have the Key value.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you post some code sample how you dictionary looks like, will be helpful !!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you have a key. So with the key, you have one value of the dictionary. This seems very simple to obtain what you want :

```
int key = 3;

var enumerable = dataTable.Where(t => t.ItemId == dictionary[key].ItemId);
```